# How to spawn and kill objects during animation to save memory?

Tags: modeling, animation

I've been struggling with this project of mine for few a days now:

I have this scene with a car being modified and tuned as it drives down a tunnel. I have a small segment of a tunnel that needs to be few km long. Using array is not an option: the scene becomes too heavy for my PC (GTX1050 with 2 GB VRAM).

Is there a way spawn and kill moving segments of the tunnel so it's not heavy — that way it might be bearable for my machine.

Also, I might need to add some sort of effect to my camera that only lets it see about 20 meters in front of it before everything disappears into dark.

You can download the file [here from OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ADZsmdFlrKe7ogQ&cid=B71BA9FEF157C86E&id=B71BA9FEF157C86E%21113&parId=root&action=locate).

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Not a direct answer, but - wouldn't it be easier to render on CPU? Then you're only limited by your RAM which is probably higher.

Comment: Haven't thought about that. I'll try it.

Comment: I thought it was a neural network correcting my text there for a second. :) Thank you!

Comment: It was a biological neural network.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas:

- One of the main problems is probably that the fan has way too many faces (you even have completely useless bolts, you certainly won't make any close-up shots on this), so you should simplify it a lot: Make it an independent object, delete a lot of edge loops,  give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with a level of 1, and an *Array* modifier so that it follows the tunnel. Tricks to simplify: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, or use select edge ring, *Select > Checker Deselect, Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve. You could also make a very simplified version if it's far away from the camera. Here is just a beginning of clean-up:

[image]

[image]

- Slide the image texture along the mesh (wall and road) with the *Mapping* node (not sure it will save a lot of memory though, lol):

[image]

- Render an image of a long tunnel perspective and use this image in your 3D scene to fake depth (or use a mirror?)
- Make only very short sequences